# jQuery | .css() Multiple Parameters '-' Error

Tags: jquery, css, string, dictionary

I have a problem with the `.css({})` function in jQuery:
I don't know exactly how this function behaves, except for that I understood that I can insert into the `{`,`}` symbols as key-value pairs (dictionary), separated by a `,`. I've tested it, and it works.

My problem with it, is that when I try to enter a CSS attribute of the form `x-y`, like `background-color`, I get an error in my code editor, and the script doesn't run. My editor gives this error about the problem:

> Expected a '`:`', and saw a '`-`'.

Why does this happen, and how can I fix this?

I'm working in TamperMonkey, if that matters.

Thanks a lot in advance,
Gal.

Comment: Woud you post the relevant code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to make the `keys` of your object `string` literals, so instead of `{text-align: 'center'}` you need `{'text-align' : 'center'}`, example:

```
$('.class').css({'text-align' : 'center', 'margin-top': '10px'});
```

And that is because when you enter `text-align` without the quotes, JavaScript will treat it as an expression, which is not expected in `json` definitions.

Comment: Hm, I understand.

If I enter a key not as a string, does Java treat it as a string? Because that works for me, if the key doesn't have a `-` in it.

Comment: Yes it does, but once you enter a `-` it will treat it as a subtraction operation, which is not expected here.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot for the information and the help. :)

Comment: You're welcome, kindly mark it as the correct answer for future references

Comment: I forgot to mark it.
Thanks for the reminder.

I marked it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're making a single CSS change, the syntax is

```
$.css('background-image','red');
```

If you're making multiple changes

```
$.css({'background-image':'red','border-bottom':'1px solid red'});
```

Comment: Like I said, I wasn't familiar with its syntax ("how exactly this function works").

I wrote in the multiple changes syntax like this, where the attributes didn't have a `-` sign:
`$("foo").css({attr1: "value1", attr2: "val2"});`

And it ran. Do you know why it ran, and why this doesn't run?

Comment: Are you putting your attribute names in quotes? They need to be interpreted as strings. Do I know why what doesn't run?